Webhook receiver not working after upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8
Webhook receiver stopped working after upgrade from .NET 6 to .NET 8. Below is the controller and method that was working in .NET 6:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/webhooks/incoming")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(object message)
    {
        try
        {
             ResponseModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(message.ToString());

             await manager.handleNotify(model);

             return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Logger.Error(ex, "Failure to access incoming webhook post");
             return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

Packages installed:
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic

Program.cs:
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();


My last few answers have been about people needing to create a class as a DTO and parse JSON in using [FromBody]. Can you replace object with a small class with a single string property and try POSTing JSON that fits the class instead of a vague object datatype. Also, if its a webhook ie API then its not an MVC app, so inherit from ControllerBase vs Controller. Lastly which route are you using the Controllers or the Method, is that the confusion?

Why are you using the webhook packages? they are ancient and are for .net framework, they don't even have .net standard 2.0 versions so can't really use them on .net 8

@ThomasSchmidt these are what's recommended in Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers Do you happen to know the latest packages?

Below is the sample code which shows .ne webhook receiver.
EController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebhookReceiver.Models;
using WebhookReceiver.Services;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<EController> _logger;
    private readonly Manager _manager;

    public EController(ILogger<EController> logger, Manager manager)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _manager = manager;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("webhooks/incoming")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] JsonElement message)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseModel>(message.GetRawText());

            await _manager.HandleNotify(model);

            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failure to access incoming webhook post");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using WebhookReceiver.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Register the Manager service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Manager>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Installed nuget packages:

Result:

